# How to pass requests from browser to an external application

Tags: google-chrome, url-scheme

If you have Steam installed, following links such as **steam://link** will result in Chrome suggesting to launch Steam:

[image: open steam client bootstrapper?]

How can I achieve the same effect for a custom app with a custom handle? Where is this behavior documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to an external mobile app or an external desktop app?

Here most likely your Steam App supports deep linking via URI Schemes, which is a common flow for being able to open apps from the mobile web.

If you wish to develop an app that supports that, you need to refer to the deep linking documentation for the platform where you develop your app.

Basically deep linking with URI schemes means that the browser tries to redirect to the `steam://link` scheme, and if there's an installed app which declared that this scheme can open it - deep link occurs.

The scenario to support that really depends on the platform you are targeting.